# How to convert the seperate json objects to an combined json object

Tags: json

I'm currently getting the JSON object like this.

```
{"name" : "Ragu", "id":"001"}
{"name" : "Guna", "id":"002"}
{"name" : "Guna1", "id":"003"}
{"name" : "Guna2", "id":"004"}
{"name" : "Guna3", "id":"005"}
```

I have to convert them into a combined JSON object.

Some thing like this

```
{
    [
    {"name" : "Ragu", "id":"001"},
    {"name" : "Guna", "id":"002"},
    {"name" : "Guna1", "id":"003"},
    {"name" : "Guna2", "id":"004"},
    {"name" : "Guna3", "id":"005"} ]
}
```

Comment: What do you mean by a combined JSON object?

Comment: Like an array? I though think `[].push({json})`

Comment: Given that the above is not valid JSON it's really hard to know what language you're even writing your code in, let alone what you're asking.

Comment: Your second block of JSON has an array inside an object, but the object has no key.., that's not even valid syntax!

Comment: hello mr joshstrike, i use spring mvc where i get objects one by one if you when drag and drop in the drop zone area. So i asked the question. So if you don't know the answer please don't give comments. I got the answer from jason sperke.